# How to record the number of SAS startups?

Tags: sas

I am designing an auto SAS program. I want it execute at the very first time I start SAS everyday and it should be executed only once. That is to say, I may start SAS several times this day, but the auto program will be executed only the first time I start SAS.

There are also some restricts:
1. It won't be executed if I have not use my SAS one day;
2. It won't be executed if I happen to working on SAS at daybreak;

I think recording the number of SAS startups is the key but have no idea on how to record it. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The title of the question is different from the actual question.

Comment: @Lee The title is the key to this question, I think.

Comment: Please clarify -  do you want it to run *exactly* once per day, or *at most* once per day? For the former a batch job is more appropriate than an autoexec entry.

Comment: Are you in PC SAS?  So when you start PC SAS, you want it to check if this is the first time SAS ran on that date, and if so, you want to %include another SAS program?  Seems like you could have the autoexec write today's date to a perm SAS dataset every time SAS starts, and before that have the autoexec check if that perm date matches &sysdate.  If the perm date already matches &sysdate, it's not the first time SAS was started that day.

Comment: If your SAS session is ended at 1am on Tuesday, and you start SAS again at 9am the same day, should or should not the 'once a day' program be run ?

Comment: @user667489 At most once per day.

Comment: @Quentin Really excellent method. I'll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as Quentin's comment

Add code such as the following to your autoexec.

```
options nodsnferr;
data _null_;
  if not exist ('sasuser.laststart') then 
    call execute ('%include "my-once-a-day.sas";');

  set sasuser.laststart;

  if date < today() then
    call execute ('%include "my-once-a-day.sas";');
run;
options nodsnferr;
data sasuser.laststart;
  date = today();
run;
```

If you run multiple concurrent SAS sessions with different autoexecs and sasuser paths the above is not sufficient.

Comment: I am not considering multiple sessions conditions, thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: Second "options nodsnferr;" should be "options dsnferr;" or it would make no sense